# How to prove $p \vee q \vdash \neg(\neg p \wedge \neg q)$?

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

I'm trying to complete a list of exercises but this question I still can not solve. Somebody could help me?

**updated: this is my conclusion**

1 - $p\vee q$ **Premise**
2 - p **Assume**
3 - $\neg p\wedge\neg q$ **Assume**
4 - $\neg p$ $\wedge$e1 of 3
5 - $\perp$ $\neg$e 2,4
6 - $\neg(\neg p\wedge\neg q)$ $\neg$i 3-5

7 - q **Assume**
8 - $\neg p\wedge\neg q$ **Assume**
9 - $\neg q$ $\wedge$e2 of 8
10 - $\perp$ $\neg$e 7,9
11 - $\neg(\neg p\wedge\neg q)$ $\neg$i 8-10
12 - **conclude** $\neg(\neg p\wedge\neg q)$  $\vee$e 1, 2-6, 7-11
*Sorry for the text organization, I'm still learning how to use correctly.

Comment: What work have you done so far?

Comment: What does the $\vdash$ symbol represent? Other than that, this looks like DeMorgan's Law

Comment: ⊢ represents logical consequence. 
I'm trying to start but I get into a point that I can not see what can I do

Comment: How are you solving other problems like these? A truth table would be overkill I guess if all you need to show is logical consequence, but it would definitely work.

Comment: I must use natural deduction

Comment: Thanks @MauroALLEGRANZA, error of translation

Comment: I was wondein about how to do this in the other direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume $p$.

Deduce $\neg (\neg p \land \neg q)$.

Assume $q$.

Deduce $\neg (\neg p \land \neg q)$.

Conclude $p \lor q \vdash \neg (\neg p \land \neg q)$

Comment: Yes, this is the idea, use $\vee$e, but deduce is the problem, I will add how I was thinking

Comment: $p$ is assumed. Now assume $(\neg p \land \neg q)$...(I don't want to do too much of the problem for you)

Comment: assume p.
$\perp$ arrive at a contradiction 
 conclude $\neg$p

do the same for q and conclude $\neg p\wedge\neg q$

but I went into a infinity loop

Comment: I understand you @GFauxPas, I don't wanna it too. I trying to understand and solve it.
whenever I have many assumptions I think that my prove can be wrong

Comment: Assume $p$. Step in. Assume $\neg p \land \neg q$. Step in. Deduce $\bot$. Step out, and you have $\neg(\neg p \land \neg q)$ with you.

Comment: Oh man, thank you very much @GFauxPas. Now i get it. I was trying by the wrong way

Comment: There's usually more than one way to prove these things, so it doesn't mean that your way was a dead end.

Comment: Yep, are you right. Is better to say that was a harder way.

Answer (score 1):

I want to consider this from a more computational perspective:

1) You can expand $\neg P$ as $P\to\,⊥$. Here "not P" is taken to mean: "A reason to believe $P$ would lead to absurdness".

So let's consider

$$(P\lor Q)\to \neg \left(\neg P\land \neg Q\right)$$

which by 1) translates to

$$(P\lor Q)\to\left(\left((P\to\,⊥)\land (Q\to\,⊥)\right) \to\,⊥\right)$$

At this point a case analysis would suffice to proof the statement. If you have a reason to believe $P$, say, then if you also had a reason to believe that $P$ (as well as $Q$) leads to absurdness, you're indeed lead to absurdness. The other case is handled analogously. This proof can expressed as

$x\mapsto\langle p,q\rangle\mapsto\mathrm{if}\ (x:P),\ \mathrm{do}\ p(x);\ \mathrm{elseif}\ (x:Q),\ \mathrm{do}\ q(x)$

2) Anyway, we can rewrite the proposition further... You can translate $P\to(Q\to R)$ to $(P\land Q)\to R$. This says "If a reason to believe $P$ implies that a reason to believe $Q$ suffices to show $R$, then, equivalently, reasons to believe both $P$ and $Q$ already imply $R$."

By this, we can rewrite the above as

$$\left((P\lor Q)\land\left((P\to\,⊥)\land (Q\to\,⊥)\right)\right) \to\,⊥$$

which, to make it more readable, we write as

$$\left((P\to\,⊥)\land (Q\to\,⊥)\land (P\lor Q)\right) \to\,⊥$$

In words, the statement just says: "Believing that $P$ is absurd and also believing that $Q$ is absurd, while at the same time believing that either $P$ or $Q$ is true ... this is absurd."

Comment: Thanks for your answer @NikolajK, It is a different resolution. I'll show my teacher and classmates in the next class

Comment: @ItaloPessoa: fyi, I translated the proof to a program in the sense of [Curry-Howard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence).